# Is it neccessary to have .Bak extension while restoring Sharepoint 2013 site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, central-administration, farm-admin

As we know there are 2 options to take backup of a site collection.

> Central Administration and Powershell

If we take Backup using central administration we first have to create one folder in any of the drive of that server then we have to give that path, so after taking backup we find all the backup files in that folder

just Imagine

I have taken backup using CA and created one folder in D: as backup

and in this folder I will be having all the .bak files.

now while Restoring I'm using Powershell and getting access to the path denied error.

Powershell command that I'm using is

> Restore-SPSite -Identity http://10.0.7.11:333/ -path F:\backup-Force

then I'm getting access to the path error.

May I know why I'm getting this and how to resolve?

[image: kindly go through the image to find the that are with .bak extensions.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to give the full path to the backup files.

```
Restore-SPSite -Identity http://10.0.7.11:333/ -path F:\backup-Force\backup.bak
```

You can read more about it here [Backup-SPsite](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607788.aspx)

**Path**: Required,System.String,
Specifies a valid path to the location of the backup. For example, C:\Backup\site_name.bak.

It should be same in both Backup and Restore method.

Comment: Thanks for your response,

But sir, how can I add .bak extension to my backup folder?
I tried by adding this but it was showing path not found error.

Comment: what you mean by adding in folder? how you get the backup of the site collection? from central admin > backup of site collection? or backup-Spsite?

Comment: Yes sir I got this backup using central administration and I did backup for site collection that has around 17GB.
first I created one folder with the name "Backup" in E:
then in CA while taking backup I have given the above path like E:Backup

after successfully completing backup process I have got various .bak files in Backup folder.

When I try to use Backup folder as a path then it's showing access denied error.

Comment: You Should mention the complete path for backup including the file name...E:\backup\Backup-Site.bak....this will create only one bak file and you will then use the same file for restore...But if you want to restore to exisitng backup files...could you please tell me what are the name looks like

Comment: I have got various files with .bak extensions.

for your information, I have taken this backup from production server
then I copied the backup folder to testing server and now I want to restore it to testing server.

Comment: tell me the file names inside the folder....i think they will have numbers in it like 0001, 002....if you dont mind then share it here

Comment: Please check my question again, I have updated with the image

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50509/discussion-between-waqas-sarwar-mcse-and-asrar).

Comment: I have texted you, Kindly check your messages.

Answer (score 1):

yes it is needed to have a specific extension say here ".bak" but it is not needed to be only that. pls refer the below article from the form.

I have tried it with .dat file as well and it worked fine. but make sure you give the completer path to the file location and apply "-force" command to overwrite the existing site collection.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/9760e077-2c66-4f50-bdb8-c0200ae126a3/what-is-the-difference-between-cab-dat-and-bak-files?forum=sharepointadminlegacy

Comment: Thank you for your response,
As you can see I have used -Force Command.

but my question is still same that how can I add .bak extension to the folder which has lot of .bak files.

Answer (score 0):

Your backup is stored in `F:\ProductionEnv` so your path should be that.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/71497)

Comment: I have given the same path sir..